# Outlook add-in is not working on desktop app

Tags: office365, outlook-addin

I am using Office365 and the latest version on windows 10, and trying to build outlook add-in.

I built Outlook add-in by following this to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator#create-the-add-in).

And I compiled the add-in using `npm run dev-server` and sideloaded the add-in by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing).

After that, I tried to use the add-in, but it seems to be only working in administrator.

Even though I run Outlook as administrator(desktop app), it doesn't work.

[image]

But if I sign out a user, and sign in as administrator, then it works.

As a normal user(even though I open Outlook by hitting "Run as administrator"), if I run the add-in, it shows the following error. And I hit restart button, then it is loading forever.

[image]

I tried to troubleshoot this, I opened Outlook in safe mode, disabled all add-ins, and tried again.

But it has failed.

And second, I re-installed or updated Office365, but it didn't work either. [reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2016/outlook-2016-will-only-run-as-an-administrator/e66ba67b-76b1-4b7d-ac3c-d53b7bb4cae5)

Is there any way to run Outlook to use add-in as normal user?

My windows 10 version is over 1903. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple reasons that could be causing this error message. But the most widely spread cause is the `Protected mode` turned off in Internet Explorer. Here is what the Outlook team states:

> This error is by-design for add-ins in Outlook clients that are rendered using IE and do not have Protected Mode enabled. Protected Mode is a security feature when using IE, and it is strongly recommend that it be enabled while using add-ins.

> If you do not or cannot enable Protected Mode, a possible workaround is to upgrade to a newer Windows and Office, so add-ins are rendered using Edge Webview instead of IE. Details about what versions that Webview are supported can be found [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/).

1. In Internet Explorer, click the `Tools` button, and then click `Internet Options`.
   2, Click the `Security` tab, and then select the `Internet Sites Zone`.
2. Select the `Enable Protected Mode` check box, and then click `Ok`.
3. Restart Internet Explorer and Outlook. Check if that helped.
4. If not, enable `Protected mode` on `Restricted Zone` and try anew.

See [Office Add-in don't start if you disable protected mode for the Restricted Sites zone in Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/apps-for-office-not-start) .

Also you may find the [Troubleshoot user errors with Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/testing-and-troubleshooting) article helpful.

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question. I removed check for `enable protected mode` in the internet options, but it still has the same issue.

Comment: Verify that the latest Office updates are installed

Comment: I re-installed Office completely, but it is the same.

Comment: Try to use Fiddler for troubleshooting the issue - what calls are made and where it fails.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried again, and it worked.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to mark the answer.